# Postman getting 401 unauthorized ... Using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to create a web application using spring boot... By my postman get all time 401 unauthorized. How to solve the problem in my case... Thanks

My application.properties file

```
############# Database Properties ############################
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/reddit_clone
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=Jsingh22.
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

My controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthController {

    private final AuthService authService;

    @PostMapping("/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<String> signUp(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        authService.signUp(registerRequest);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("User Registration Successfully", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My security class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }
}
```

I am trying to lot of solution StackOverflow... But my case not accepted that solution
How to solve my problem?

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling? seems only `/api/auth/**` is open, so you should hit *401* for all others.

Comment: @Aman This is my URL,  http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup/

Comment: you have to `@Autowire` `private final AuthService authService;`

Comment: did you reach the method body? or did you get the 401 from the authservice?

Comment: and your spring security debug logs tell you what?